# How many A records can fit in a single DNS response?

Tags: math, dns, protocols

What are the size limits on DNS responses? For instance how many 'A' [resource records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) can be present in a single DNS response?  The DNS response should still be cache-able.

Comment: UDP, or TCP?  (DNS will fall back to TCP if the response is too large.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest *guaranteed* supported DNS message size is 512 bytes.

Of those, 12 are used up by the header (see §4.1.1 of [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)).

The *Question Section* appears next, but is of variable length - specifically it'll be:

- the domain name (in wire format)
- two bytes each for *QTYPE* and *QCLASS*

Hence the longer your domain name is, the less room you have left over for answers.

Assuming that *label compression* is used (§4.1.4), each `A` record will require:

- two bytes for the compression pointer
- two bytes each for *TYPE* and *CLASS*
- four bytes for the *TTL*
- two bytes for the *RDLENGTH*
- four bytes for the A record data itself

i.e. 16 bytes for each A record (§4.1.3).

You should *if possible* also include your NS records in the *Authority Section*.

Given all that, you might squeeze *around* 25 records into one response.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-respsize-12), the limit is based on the UDP message size limit, which is 512 octets.  The EDNS standard supports a negotiated response with a virtually unlimited response size, but at the time of that writing (March 2011), only 65% of clients supported it (which means you can't really rely on it)

Comment: The real EDNS limit is 64k bytes, and most servers cap it at 4k.

Comment: p.s. that document is an _internet draft_.  It's not yet an RFC.