# What is the maximum amount of resource records in DNS response?

Tags: dns

I need to know what is the maximum amount of resource records in a single DNS response?
Does it has a limit at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794926/how-many-a-records-can-fit-in-a-single-dns-response#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=The%20largest%20guaranteed%20supported%20DNS,1%20of%20RFC%201035).)

Comment: @H.Udara If there's too much record to fit a UDP packet, the server would return an error and tell to retry with TCP, at which point it can send 4095 records https://ethanheilman.tumblr.com/post/110920218915/how-many-ip-addresses-can-dns-query-return

Comment: OP, see https://serverfault.com/questions/652237/whats-the-maximum-number-of-ips-a-dns-a-record-can-have, so the practical limit is usually enough for most cases, and once you go over the UDP limit (or even before that), you're usually better off just using anycast